# SQL select column values based on 2 dates

Tags: sql, select, join

I have a select statement that is large and built from many other tables and joins.

I need another select statement that contains the same data but is base on 2 different dates.

the current select results in the following

```
Date       |   ID   |Account|Prod|Location|Cost|Owner  |
10-10-2017 | #73818 | B17H12|M104|EastNY  |400 |Jay Bob|
10-11-2017 | #77618 | B16H14|M104|EastNY  |200 |Jay Bob|
10-11-2017 | #73818 | B17H12|M106|WestNY  |300 |Jay Bob|
10-10-2017 | #75543 | B13H17|M106|WestNY  |900 |Jay Bob|
```

the new statement i need to compare the same as above but return the state of 2 different dates that i choose, say the 10th and the 11th so the table would be as such

```
Owner    |   ID    | Account |    Date 1  | Prod |Location | Cost | Date 2     | Prod | Location |Cost|
Jay Bob  |  #73818 | B17H12  | 10-10-2017 | M104 | EastNY  | 400  | 10-11-2017 | M106 | EastNY    |300 |
Jay Bob  |  #77618 | B16H14  | 10-10-2017 | NULL |   NULL  | NULL | 10-11-2017 | M104 | EastNY    |200 |
Jay Bob  |  #75543 | B13H17  | 10-10-2017 | M106 | WestNY  | 900  | 10-11-2017 | NULL | NULL      |NULL|
```

Here is the original scrubbed statement
unit.sample_date has the dates and unit.entity_id is the ID
I wont need many of these lines in the cases and such but some i will need the select i need is a subset of these comparing columns from the 2 different dates.

```
    with temp as (select platform as pltfrm, total_01, total_02, entity_identification.display_name as Platform from hardware
    LEFT join host_info on hardware.id = host_info.hardware_id
    left join entity_identification on host_info.entity_id = entity_identification.entity_id 
     where platform= 'Plat01')
    select unit.sample_date,
      entity_identification.display_name as hostname,
      entity_identification.object_id,
      pim.[Product_Code] as 'PrdCode',
      pim.ProductName,
      ha4.attr_value as Region,
      ha5.attr_value as Plat01_Account,
      ha1.attr_value as 'Environment',
      ha2.attr_value as 'Inventory_Code',
      ha3.attr_value as 'moving_Group',
      enid01.object_id as 'moving_Group_ID',
      unit.exist_space_type as 'Current_space_type',
      unit.recomm_space_type as 'Recommended_space_type',
      CASE
        when ha.attr_value IS NULL then 'N/A' else ha.attr_value end as 'Price_Model',
      unit.exist_cost as 'Current_space_Cost',
      unit.recomm_cost as 'Recommended_space_Cost',
      unit.exist_cost - unit.recomm_cost as 'Savings_Month',
      (unit.exist_cost - unit.recomm_cost) / 30 as 'Savings_Daily',
      CASE 
        when unit.exist_cost > unit.recomm_cost AND ((unit.recomm_space_type not like 'idle%')  AND (substring(unit.recomm_space_type, 0, 2) != substring(unit.exist_space_type, 0, 2))) then 'too_much'
        when unit.exist_cost < unit.recomm_cost  AND ((unit.recomm_space_type not like 'idle%') AND (substring(unit.recomm_space_type, 0, 2) != substring(unit.exist_space_type, 0, 2))) then 'too_little' 
        when unit.exist_cost = unit.recomm_cost then 'Just_Right' 
        when substring(unit.recomm_space_type, 0, 2) = substring(unit.exist_space_type, 0, 2) then 'update'
        when unit.recomm_space_type like 'idle%' then 'remove' end as 'Status_On_Date',

      v_system_info_hist.total_01 as 'Cur_LT01_Total_T01Low',
      ((unit.exist_cost) / (v_system_info_hist.total_01)*1000) as 'Cur_Cost_Per_T01',
      case
        when temp.total_01 IS NULL then 0 else temp.total_01 end as 'Rec_Total_LT01_T01Low',
      case
        when temp.total_01 IS NULL then 0 else ((unit.recomm_cost) / (temp.total_01)*1000) end as 'Rec_Cost_Per_T01',
      case
        when temp.total_01 IS NULL then ((unit.exist_cost) / (v_system_info_hist.total_01)*1000) else ( ((unit.exist_cost) / (v_system_info_hist.total_01)*1000)-((unit.recomm_cost) / (temp.total_01)*1000) ) end as 'Savings_per_T01',
        case
        when temp.total_02 IS NULL then ((unit.exist_cost) / (v_system_info_hist.total_02)) else  ((unit.exist_cost/v_system_info_hist.total_01)*temp.total_01) - (unit.recomm_cost) end as 'LT01_Projected_Total_Potential_Cost_Saving',
      v_system_info_hist.total_02 as 'Cur_T02_Count',
      unit.exist_cost / v_system_info_hist.total_02 as 'Cur_Cost_Per_T02',
      case
        when temp.total_02 IS NULL then 0 else temp.total_02 end as 'Rec_T02_Count',
      case
        when temp.total_02 IS NULL then 0 else ((unit.recomm_cost) / (temp.total_02)) end as 'Rec_Cost_Per_T02',
      case
        when temp.total_02 IS NULL then ((unit.exist_cost) / (v_system_info_hist.total_02)) else ( ((unit.exist_cost) / (v_system_info_hist.total_02))-((unit.recomm_cost) / (temp.total_02)) ) end as 'Savings_per_T02',
      case
        when temp.total_02 IS NULL then ((unit.exist_cost) / (v_system_info_hist.total_02)) else ( ((unit.exist_cost/v_system_info_hist.total_02)*temp.total_02) - (unit.recomm_cost)  ) end as 'T02_Projected_Total_Potential_Cost_Saving',
      case
        when ha6.attr_value IS NULL AND unit.exist_cost > unit.recomm_cost AND ((unit.recomm_space_type not like 'idle%')  AND (substring(unit.recomm_space_type, 0, 2) != substring(unit.exist_space_type, 0, 2))) then 85
        when ha6.attr_value IS NULL AND unit.exist_cost < unit.recomm_cost  AND ((unit.recomm_space_type not like 'idle%') AND (substring(unit.recomm_space_type, 0, 2) != substring(unit.exist_space_type, 0, 2))) then 80
        when ha6.attr_value IS NULL AND unit.exist_cost = unit.recomm_cost then 5
        when ha6.attr_value IS NULL AND substring(unit.recomm_space_type, 0, 2) = substring(unit.exist_space_type, 0, 2) then 88 
        when ha6.attr_value IS NULL AND unit.recomm_space_type like 'idle%' then 90 else ha6.attr_value end as 'Confidence_Score',
      case
        when ha7.attr_value IS NULL AND unit.exist_cost > unit.recomm_cost AND ((unit.recomm_space_type not like 'idle%')  AND (substring(unit.recomm_space_type, 0, 2) != substring(unit.exist_space_type, 0, 2))) then 3
        when ha7.attr_value IS NULL AND unit.exist_cost < unit.recomm_cost  AND ((unit.recomm_space_type not like 'idle%') AND (substring(unit.recomm_space_type, 0, 2) != substring(unit.exist_space_type, 0, 2))) then 5
        when ha7.attr_value IS NULL AND unit.exist_cost = unit.recomm_cost then 5
        when ha7.attr_value IS NULL AND substring(unit.recomm_space_type, 0, 2) = substring(unit.exist_space_type, 0, 2) then 2
        when ha7.attr_value IS NULL AND unit.recomm_space_type like 'idle%' then 2 else ha7.attr_value end as 'PSFT_Ticket_Sev',
      pim.SeniorTechOwner,
      pim.TechOwner,
      pim.SupportEmail,
      pim.SeniorProductOwner,
      pim.PSFT,
      pim.SlackChannel,
      v_ig.ig_name as Availability_Zone,
      pim.[Asset_Id] as 'Asset_Id'
     FROM [dbo].[unit_u_transfer_hist] unit 
     LEFT JOIN host_attributes on host_attributes.host_name = unit.entity_id and host_attributes.attr_key = 'attr_5'
     LEFT JOIN host_attributes ha on ha.host_name = unit.entity_id and ha.attr_key = 'attr_10'
     LEFT JOIN host_attributes ha1 on ha1.host_name = unit.entity_id and ha1.attr_key = 'attr_3'
     LEFT JOIN host_attributes ha2 on ha2.host_name = unit.entity_id and ha2.attr_key = 'attr_4' 
     LEFT JOIN host_attributes ha3 on ha3.host_name = unit.entity_id and ha3.attr_key = 'attr_9'
     LEFT JOIN host_attributes ha4 on ha4.host_name = unit.entity_id and ha4.attr_key = 'VE_LOCATION_DATA'
     LEFT JOIN host_attributes ha5 on ha5.host_name = unit.entity_id and ha5.attr_key = 'VE_LOCATION_DOM'
     LEFT JOIN host_attributes ha6 on ha6.host_name = unit.entity_id and ha6.attr_key = 'attr_14'
     LEFT JOIN host_attributes ha7 on ha7.host_name = unit.entity_id and ha7.attr_key = 'attr_15'
     LEFT JOIN v_system_info_hist on v_system_info_hist.entity_id = unit.entity_id and dbo.v_system_info_hist.sample_date = unit.sample_date
     LEFT JOIN entity_identification enid01  on v_system_info_hist.parent_entity_id = enid01.entity_id and dbo.v_system_info_hist.sample_date =  unit.sample_date
     LEFT JOIN temp on unit.recomm_space_type like temp.platform+'%'

     LEFT JOIN v_ig on v_ig.ig_id = unit.ig_id
     LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ud_tkm_pimm] pim on pim.[Product_Code] = Replace(host_attributes.attr_value, 'PRD00000','PRD') 
     OR pim.[Product_Code] = Replace(host_attributes.attr_value, 'PRD0000','PRD') 
     LEFT JOIN entity_identification on entity_identification.entity_id = unit.entity_id
 where unit.sample_date >= DATEADD(day, -13, GETDATE()) ORDER BY PrdCode desc
```

Comment: what rdbms and is the query so large it can't be posted as well?

Comment: Not about how large it is (90 lines) more about confidentiality.
I will see if i can scrub it and post it.

Comment: That's fine what rdbms?

Comment: Which dbms?  You will get different answer for different dbms.  It's useless if you get answer to the wrong dbms.  I don't know how this post get upvoted.  Missing tag, no attempt.

Comment: the database is MS SQL

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a database so I went with SQL Server syntax.  You will need to subselect the two dates and then full outer join.

```
DECLARE @first datetime, @second datetime
SELECT @first='10/10/2017', @second='10/11/2017'

SELECT isnull(first.Owner, second.Owner) Owner,
    isnull(first.ID, second.ID) ID,
    isnull(first.Account, second.Account) Account,
    @first [Date 1],
    first.Prod,
    first.Location,
    first.Cost,
    @second [Date 2],
    second.Prod,
    second.Location,
    second.Cost 
FROM
(SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date=@first) first
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date=@second) second
    ON first.Owner=second.Owner 
        and first.ID=second.ID
        and first.Account=second.Account
```

Comment: Sorry it is MS SQL - I Added the full query I have currently in the original post above.

Comment: Ok, perfect.  then the above code should work for you

Answer (score 0):

From your result sets it looks like your 2 dates are based on 2 different records with the same ID.  It's hard to tell you how to do this without seeing the details of the tables you are querying from, but the basic idea would be to left join the table again on the ID and the condition that makes them different

i.e.

```
    SELECT d.ID, d.Date AS Date1, d2.Date AS Date2
    FROM IDTABLE d
    LEFT JOIN IDTABLE d2
    ON d.ID=d2.ID
    AND d2.Date<d1.Date
```